# How to get custom webpart have its table rendering overlay other SP Online page elements below it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

I'm authoring custom web parts with SPFx. I've tried fiddling with the CSS z-index and even with setting the lower page part , that is, the part-to-be-overlaid to negative value with the part lexically above its z-index a positive value when the upper component renders a table it is hidden underneath the lower web part. What is the proper way to accomplish this?

[image]